# Comparison of model structures

Tags: model-categories

I am just learning some basics of model categories, so pardon me if my question is trivial.

Suppose that $\mathfrak{C}$ is a category and there exists two model structures on $\mathfrak{C}$ (For example consider flat and injective model structures on R-Modules). Then which conditions are needed to verify that two model structures are equivalent?

In particular I want to know if the injective and flat model structure on $R$-Mod when the ring $R$ is a Noetherian ring, are equivalent.

Comment: Just follow the definition of Quillen equivalence...?

Comment: Do you have Hirschhorn or Hovey?

Comment: Yes, I have Hovey's book, but I can't find any statement concerning the comparison of model structures.